# Difficulty function isn't working Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a snippet of code to ask the user what difficulty they would like to play on. My easy statement works. However, if I enter "hard", it doesn't do anything but print out the message again.

```
diff = ''
while not diff == 'easy' or diff == 'hard':
    diff = input('What difficulty? [easy/hard] ') # HARD not working!
    diff = diff.lower()

    if diff == "hard":
        word = random.choice(words.hangman_words)
        word = word.upper()
    elif diff == "easy":
        word = random.choice(wordseasy.hangman_words_easy)
        word = word.upper()
    else: 
        print('Invalid answer. Try again.')
```

Comment: Oh, and I have properly imported the words.hangman_words/words.hangman_words_easy. That isn't the problem.

Comment: `not diff == 'easy' or diff == 'hard'` means `(not diff == 'easy') or diff == 'hard'`. You mean `while diff != 'easy' and diff != 'hard'`. Or `while diff not in ('easy', 'hard')`.

Comment: I think DeMorgan would like to have a word...

Comment: It should be `while not (diff == 'easy' or diff == 'hard'):` because of the relative precedence of `not` and `or`.

Comment: try `while diff not in ["easy", "hard"]:`

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is your while loop.
Give this a try. You continue until `diff` is equal to 'hard' or 'easy.

```
while diff != 'easy' and diff != 'hard':
```

Comment: `diff != 'easy' or diff != 'hard'` is always true.

Comment: noooo. I think you saw that wrong. and ofcourse I would have never edited my post. never ever.

Comment: The perfect crime.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
diff = ''
while not (diff == 'easy' or diff == 'hard'): #notice parentheses
    diff = input('What difficulty? [easy/hard] ') # HARD not working!
    diff = diff.lower()

    if diff == "hard":
        word = random.choice(words.hangman_words)
        word = word.upper()
    elif diff == "easy":
        word = random.choice(wordseasy.hangman_words_easy)
        word = word.upper()
    else: 
        print('Invalid answer. Try again.')
```

Why this works:

You'll have to read up on operator precedence in Python a bit to understand what's going on here. The idea is that while not diff == 'easy' or diff == 'hard' only applies "not" to diff == 'easy'

Answer (score 0):

The `not` in `while not diff == 'easy' or diff == 'hard':` applies only to the first condition, `diff == 'easy'`.

Try `while not (diff == 'easy' or diff == 'hard'):`